# What does mean this error in python?

Tags: python, loops, indentation

```
list = []
for df in lp:
           list.append(list(df.loc[985191]))
        list(list of list)
T = pd.DataFrame(list)
```

Hi I have this code to `python` but when I returned, shows me an error

> IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

what can be the error?

Comment: The indentation of statement "list.append(..)" and "list(list...") should be the same.

Comment: You should have the lines that start with `list.append(` and `list(list of` indented to the same column.

Also, note that calling your variable `list` shadows a builtin name and will cause additional problems.

Comment: @BrianCain Do you know how can I fix that about the list, cause I 've already fix the indented but you're right, it shows me another problem with the list

Comment: Don't assign to a name called `list`, think of it as a reserved name.
e.g. `something = []` and not `list = []`.  What is `list(list of list)` supposed to do?

Comment: @BrianCain It's supposed join all the columns of lp. lp is a list from 40 dataframes, and I want to extract all the same column names of those dataframes and put in a singles df acording the column name

Comment: Try and ask a new SO question about that one and the error you're getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You indented this line `list.append(list(df.loc[985191]))` too far in. Try this.

```
 list = []
    for df in lp:
            list.append(list(df.loc[985191]))
            list(list of list)
    T = pd.DataFrame(list)
```